# Dovecot Require Client Certificate for Remote Connections Only

Tags: ssl, dovecot, tls, roundcube

After a bit of a struggle I've managed to configure Dovecot to require client certificates for users logging in, and it works well.

However, I also want to setup a web-mail solution (Roundcube) which needs to be able to connect via IMAP, but doesn't appear to be capable of sending a client certificate. I'm configuring it to use port 143 (unencrypted) as the connection occurs over a trusted network, and with this in mind I've added my local network to Dovecot's `login_trusted_networks` so that plaintext authentication works as well.

Unfortunately when Roundcube connects, it's still being asked for a client certificate even though the connection doesn't have SSL enabled.

I've already limited the requirement for client certificates to avoid issues with postfix using the following:

```
protocol !smtp {
    ssl_ca = </etc/dovecot/ca/dovecot-ca.pem
    ssl_verify_client_cert = yes
    ssl_cert_username_field = commonName

    auth_ssl_require_client_cert = yes
    auth_ssl_username_from_cert = yes
}
```

However I don't know how I can restrict this further to only encrypted connections? I don't allow remote access to unencrypted protocols, except for port 25 as necessary for sending e-mail between servers.

As a security note, the same certificate protecting IMAPS connections is also used for client authentication by `nginx`, so the webmail is already restricted by certificate, though I may switch for some other second layer of authentication for mobility (e.g- some kind of two-factor API).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Roundcube to supply a client certificate to Dovecot.  In Roundcube's config.inc.php:

$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://localhost';

$config['default_port'] = 993;

// IMAP socket context options

// See https://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

// Supply client certificate over SSL, required by Dovecot

$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(

'ssl'         => array(

```
 'local_cert'   => '/Path/To/YourRoundcubeClient.crt',

 'local_pk'     => '/Path/To/YourRoundcubeClient.key'
```

),

);